# 12bit int stored in 2Bytes to 8bit

Tags: byte, bit, grayscale

I have to get a 12bit int stored in 2 bytes, and then convert it to 8 bit. I tried the following:

```
    (byte[i]+byte[i+1]<<8)&0xff;
```

It did not work as intended and I have been searching for the answer for a while.

EDIT: Big-endian sequencing.
Thank you

Comment: why not just cast? what bits are you trying to get? 8LSbs or 4 0s and 4MSbs?

Comment: I am using processing, no cast there. It is LSbs.

Comment: then just cast to `uint8_t` or `int8_t`, whichever you prefer, or `&0xff`, or `%255`, all same thing.